# Remove all occurences of new lines and tabs

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm still in the process of learning some decent regex but I would have thought this would work.

This works:

```
str.replace(/   /g,"").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

But a shorter version of this, does not. Where did I go wrong?

```
str.replace((/  /g)|(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm),"");
```

Comment: I believe that your first (working) example is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The regexpr delimiter is `/`, so you have the "or" `|` out of the expression. If you want to join them try with

```
str.replace((/  |\r\n|\n|\r/gm),"");
```

By the way, the tab character is `\t` in a regexp, so if you want to remove all tabs and new lines you can use `str.replace(/[\t\n\r]/gm,'');` Said this, if with "tab" you mean any identation including "4 white spaces", then use `str.replace(/ {4}|[\t\n\r]/gm,'');`

Comment: I like this answer, especially because you explain everything very well. That's good for a beginner in RegEx, as I am in.

Comment: Using the recommended way to include 4 spaces is buggy, as it will incorrectly match to the literal number 4. Use this instead: `str.replace(/ {4}|[\t\n\r]/gm,'');`.

Answer (score 12):

Instead of all the OR operators, you might want to just group them like this:

```
str = "Hello\n" +
      "there    stranger!";

str.replace(/[\r\n\t]/g, "")
// "Hellotherestranger!"
```

The `[` and `]` group means 'any character from within this group', it's cleaner than all the OR expressions.

Comment: This is a great recommendation, especially if you were going to be removing other characters in addition to tabs and newlines

Answer (score 2):

You should do like below (combine two regex into one):

```
str = str.replace(/  |\r\n|\n|\r/gm, '');
```

For 2 space, you could also write:

```
str = str.replace(/ {2}|\r\n|\n|\r/gm, '');
```

Comment: I would place the space in brackets, it looks nicer: `str = replace(/[ ]{2}|\r\n|\n|\r/gm, '');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
str.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|(  ))/gm,"");
```