# How to clean result of cheerio request?

Tags: javascript, cheerio

I wrote a request to a website using cheerio.

Here is a part of the code:

```
var title = $(this).find('.item-title').text();
var episode = $(this).find('.is-right .is-serie').first('.is-serie').text();
var type = $(this).find('.is-right .is-serie').last('.is-serie').text();
```

But as a result I got titles with symbols `\n\t` :

```
{
  title: '\n\tGiven\n\t',
  episode: '3/11',
  type: 'subtitles'
} 
{
  title: '\n\tIsekai Cheat Magician, Isekai Cheat Majutsushi\n\t',
  episode: '3/12',
  type: 'subtitles'
}
```

HTML itself is clean:

```
<div class="item-title">Given</div>
```

**How can I get rid of those symbols?**

Comment: I have a hunch that the `<div>` you shared as a single line isn't actually a single line in your code. Those 'symbols' represent newlines and tabs. Possible duplicate of [Remove all occurences of new lines and tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322572/remove-all-occurences-of-new-lines-and-tabs)

Comment: If you didn't want to get rid of them in code, then you can modify your HTML to appear exactly as you've shown it in your question (one line, no line-breaks, no tabs). [**Here's a demo** (see console)](https://jsfiddle.net/4s5fLvhu/)

Comment: Just call `.text().trim()`.